# In Assembla - SVN just an admin can make a new repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, assembla

My question is completely explained in the title XD

I want to know for making a new repository in server (not a local repository) I must be the admin ?

Comment: If you want to discuss how your questions are received, please post a question on [meta]; but be prepared to search before you ask (there too).

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the tags, on the left. You may need to use a browser, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the Owner Permissions in order to install a new tool.

If you have this Permission you can go to Admin->Tools and Add an SVN repo from there.

If you do not have this permission, then you must ask the owner of the space.

Further Documentation is here: https://articles.assembla.com/using-subversion/getting-started/get-started-with-svn